# What is the difference between = and =+ in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am beginner in Excel. I have a workbook in which the formula column is defined as

`=+TEXT($A36,"mmm")`, but even if I give `=Text($A36,"mmm")` 
it is returning the Month.

What is the difference in using `=+` and `+` in Excel?

Will it changes the functionality in any ways?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference. It's the exact same thing.

It comes from an old syntax used in [Lotus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_1-2-3)

Comment: Thanks mehow. I was wondering if this has to do anything with the functionality of the Functions in the Excel. Thanks again.

Answer (score 23):

This is simply a legacy way of doing it. From Lotus 123 I believe. It makes absolutely no difference to the functionality.

Comment: +1 for being first in with the answer.